# Rails: $variable = HTML <form><input> type="text"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variables, global-variables, forms

I have another question. I am sure that it is really really easy to answer to you but I just don´t know how to do it.
I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9.
In a view I want to define some variables which works fine like this:

```
<p>
  <b>Artikelnummer:</b>
  <%= @artikel.artikelnummer %>
</p>
  <%= $aktArtNr = @artikel.artikelnummer %>
```

But now I want to save some User input (which should not cause a controller action or something else) in a variable - and I don´t know how to do it.

P.e. I want to save the "thing" that the user types into this form

```
<form name="Menge">
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

in a variable called `$aktMenge`

It must be so easy but i´ve been trying this for a long time without success (but with getting a headache...)

P.S. after I just call a controller action which should do something with the variable...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to see what you're trying to do. My suggestion would be to have a play around with Rails scaffolding so you can see how this works from the controller through to the views. e.g. open a terminal and try (maybe in a new project):

```
rails generate scaffold artikel name:string content:text ref_number:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Then go and look in your browser at "localhost:[port_no]/artikels" and you should be able to create, update and delete records through the web interface. Then go and have a look at the code generated to see if you can relate it to what you're doing.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your reply. In fact i did generate some scaffolds and am experiencing all this REST stuff...

Comment: So far my app/experiment works quite well, but i just don´t get how to restfully implement this: show all articles (:controller => articles, :action => "index")... then i integrated into this list after each article a link which shows the article and shall give the user/customer the possibility to take a look at this article and then, if he/she wants, choose a certain amount (which shall be typed in some textfield or wherever)... )ok, maybe i have to add that this app will (probably) never be used for selling real stuff but only to hand some working app to my teacher...).

Comment: my idea would be, that after launching another link_to some method, an order_item is created which contains the articles data (this works with the variables defined above) and in addition to this an attribute called "amount" which stems from the user input into this textfield? did you get what i want to do?? i know (or at least i´m quite sure) that this is not how you would do it, but is there a possibility of doing it anyway???? (i´m almost done with my project, but this "little thing" is still missing :-( )

Answer (score 0):

Once again sorry for being new about all this RESTful stuff. I realized that due to the fact that i didn´t really know what exactly rails can do, i didn´t answer the right Question...

But this solved my problem:

[Rails getting single values from request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752913/rails-getting-single-values-from-request)