# Rails getting single values from request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, actioncontroller

in Rails the create method in a Controller by default receives an HTTP request with different values.
By default new records are created like this:

```
@apo = Apo.new(params[:apo])
```

But how can i access single Values from this params hash?

I would like to create something like this:

```
@apo = Apo.new do |a|
        a.name = $someVariable
        a.value = $anotherVariable
        a.quantity = -> here i want to have one value which is in params[:apo]
        end
```

Do you understand what i´m looking for?
Tried million possibilities but it just doesn´t work.

Alternatively, is it possible, to create a second params hash in the view, which only saves this one value?

P.S. i don´t want to use JavaScript for doing this...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is special, and is set by Rails for each HTTP request.  It's a hash in the form

```
{ :object => { :attrib1 => "value1", :attrib2 => "value2" ... }}
```

So you can reference the entire object with

```
params[:foo]
```

and individual attributes (fields) like

```
params[:foo][:bar]
```

A ActiveRecord model can be created in one call by passing a hash of values, as in your first example.  But there are many other ways to create an instance.  You can

```
def make_apo(some_value, another_value)
  apo = Apo.new
  apo.name = some_value
  apo.value = another_value
end
```

Such a method will return an instance of Apo.  In your case, if you have some values in `params`, change the above to accept `params` as another argument, or pass specific values when you call.

```
def make_apo(some_value, another_value, quantity, passed_params)
  apo = Apo.new
  apo.name = some_value
  apo.value = another_value
  apo.quantity = passed_params[:apo][:quantity]
end
```

But this is all a pretty unusual way of going about things.  So don't just do this -- it's more by way of explaining what's going on than suggesting that you do this.

Comment: Oh that was exactly the answer i was looking for... thank you so much!